# how to remove one js file from bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

How do I block one JavaScript file from the gem? I'm using the **twitter-bootstrap gem**. When the rails application loads, the gem will load all the JS files, so I want to block **scrollspy.js** from running.

Comment: See [link](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/443). Add the required files in application.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just import the files you want by `@import 'File name'`